# How to return results from single category in this query?

Tags: wordpress

How can I return the latest post from category 84 in this query?

```
<?php
            /*$args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=>'10', 'post_no_in'=>$do_not_duplicate);*/
            $args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_no_in'=>$do_not_duplicate);
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            query_posts("cat=84&showposts=1&orderby=DESC");
            if($query->have_posts()){
            while(have_posts()) : the_post();   
            /*$do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_ID();*/  ?>
            <div>
               <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                 <div class="instruction">
                <div class="home_title">MOST READ</div>
                <div class="home_title_desc"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>
                 </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

I've tried 'cat' => 84, in the array, but no go. Can you show me how to return results only from category 84?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is really messy and actually attemps to run two queries in a row; one of them using `query_posts()` which is never a good idea ([see here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) for some explanation).

Here's the query rewritten for you, getting the latest post from category 84 as requested:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => 84,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

For information on what each of these arguments do, see the [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). In particular, it's the `posts_per_page` argument that tells Wordpress to only return one post for you.

I've left out `'post_no_in'=>$do_not_duplicate` from your original code because I'm not sure what it is doing, but if you want to ask about that feel free, or you can find the appropriate argument in the WP_Query documentation and add it to the `$args` array above.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to add all the code, because everytime I enter your code I get nothing, you you please help me fix this up? Thanks a bunch

Comment: What do you mean by "get nothing"? The query returns no posts? Can you edit in how the code looks after you've inserted the rewritten query above?

Comment: If i drop your code in, and place the ending brackets after the endwhile I get a white page.

Comment: That means there's a PHP error of some sort. Can you turn on WP_DEBUG (Google for how) and edit your post to show how the code looks when you've dropped it in?

Comment: Thanks! That makes it really clear. I thought this might've been the case, gotta be careful when dropping code in. After `the_post();`, you need to include `?>` to end the block of PHP code. What's happening at the moment is PHP is trying to parse the HTML code (`<div>`) that comes next, and it's not PHP, so it's throwing a fatal error. You'll also need to drop the `endwhile;`, and put a second curly bracket next to the one under it. These two curly brackets together are ending the `if` and `while` clauses that we started earlier. Also, the two `}}` on their own on the last line can be removed

Comment: That should resolve the [white screen of death](http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors), but if it doesn't, please switch on WP_DEBUG and let me know what it outputs.

Comment: You've got 3 x `}` down at the bottom of the file. You need 2 inside the `<?php ?>` tags, and you can remove the other one.

Comment: Replace `<?php } ?> }` with `<?php } } ?>`

Comment: ok, i have done this: http://pastebin.com/UQu3nyZC and does not show post at all, i have enabled WP_DEBUG and nothing shows up around this code.

Comment: I've just added the code to my own Wordpress install and it works fine, returning to me all 3 posts in a category I chose, with the thumbnail, title, and text saying 'MOST SHAREWORTHY'. I'm afraid there's not much more I can do to help with this; I know you've told me privately you're looking for a freelancer so you might need to proceed and do that, as it seems there's obviously something specific to your site going on.

Comment: I'd also recommend doing an online PHP tutorial, as a grasp of some of the basics will help you debug your own code. StackOverflow really isn't meant as a code writing service; it helps you work out concepts you're struggling with in your own code. Try something like https://teamtreehouse.com/library/php-basics or http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/

Comment: yeah it's gotta be something else then. Good to know, I'll check this out later. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: No problem. If it has helped you, would appreciate the answer being marked as correct =)

Answer (score 0):

ahh, `query_posts("cat=84&showposts=1&orderby=DESC");`

Comment: Careful with this. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts